can I directly call a workflow from within a composite action?
Can I directly call a workflow from within a composite action?
This is my composite action:
name:   Service composite
description: Service composite
inputs:
    example_input:
      description: example input
      required: true
      type: string

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: Service test
      id: Service_test
      shell: bash
      run: |
        echo "run the test1"
        echo "echo the inputs: ${{inputs.example_input}}"

    - name: call the workflow
      uses: ./.github/workflows/call_in_action_helper.yml

And this is my helper:
name: call in action

on:
  workflow_call:

jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      data: ${{ steps.generate.outputs.data }}
    steps:
      - name: Generate data
        id: generate
        run: |
          echo "Hello from Job 1" > data.txt
          echo "data=$(cat data.txt)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: Service test
      id: Service_test
      shell: bash
      run: |
        echo "run the test1"
        echo "echo the inputs: ${{inputs.example_input}}"

    - name: call the workflow
      uses: ./.github/workflows/call_in_action_helper.yml


You can't call a workflow as part of a composite action. Reusable workflows live at the job level, a composite action is at the step level. Your second workflow mixes composite action syntax (using: composite) with workflow syntax. Lastly, it's unclear what's in call_in_action_helper.yml.

You can not call a reusable workflow from an action for reasons explained by @Benjamin W in his comment above. If you need to invoke both, you would need to define your reusable workflow so that it calls the action first and then performs the other steps that you need. Then you would invoke the reusable workflow as a job in your main workflow.
